# Multiprocessing Queue.get() hangs

Tags: python, database, queue, multiprocessing

I'm trying to implement basic multiprocessing and I've run into an issue. The python script is attached below.

```
import time, sys, random, threading
from multiprocessing import Process
from Queue import Queue
from FrequencyAnalysis import FrequencyStore, AnalyzeFrequency

append_queue = Queue(10)
database = FrequencyStore()

def add_to_append_queue(_list):
    append_queue.put(_list)

def process_append_queue():
    while True:
        item = append_queue.get()
        database.append(item)
        print("Appended to database in %.4f seconds" % database.append_time)
        append_queue.task_done()
    return

def main():
    database.load_db()
    print("Database loaded in %.4f seconds" % database.load_time)
    append_queue_process = Process(target=process_append_queue)
    append_queue_process.daemon = True
    append_queue_process.start()
    #t = threading.Thread(target=process_append_queue)
    #t.daemon = True
    #t.start()

    while True:
        path = raw_input("file: ")
        if path == "exit":
            break
        a = AnalyzeFrequency(path)
        a.analyze()
        print("Analyzed file in %.4f seconds" % a._time)
        add_to_append_queue(a.get_results())

    append_queue.join()
    #append_queue_process.join()
    database.save_db()
    print("Database saved in %.4f seconds" % database.save_time)
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

The AnalyzeFrequency analyzes the frequencies of words in a file and `get_results()` returns a sorted list of said words and frequencies. The list is very large, perhaps 10000 items.

This list is then passed to the `add_to_append_queue` method which adds it to a queue. The process_append_queue takes the items one by one and adds the frequencies to a "database". This operation takes a bit longer than the actual analysis in `main()` so I am trying to use a seperate process for this method. When I try and do this with the threading module, everything works perfectly fine, no errors. When I try and use Process, the script hangs at `item = append_queue.get()`.

Could someone please explain what is happening here, and perhaps direct me toward a fix?

All answers appreciated!

**UPDATE**

**The pickle error was my fault, it was just a typo. Now I am using the Queue class within multiprocessing but the append_queue.get() method still hangs.
NEW CODE**

```
import time, sys, random
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from FrequencyAnalysis import FrequencyStore, AnalyzeFrequency

append_queue = Queue()
database = FrequencyStore()

def add_to_append_queue(_list):
    append_queue.put(_list)

def process_append_queue():
    while True:
        database.append(append_queue.get())
        print("Appended to database in %.4f seconds" % database.append_time)
    return

def main():
    database.load_db()
    print("Database loaded in %.4f seconds" % database.load_time)
    append_queue_process = Process(target=process_append_queue)
    append_queue_process.daemon = True
    append_queue_process.start()
    #t = threading.Thread(target=process_append_queue)
    #t.daemon = True
    #t.start()

    while True:
        path = raw_input("file: ")
        if path == "exit":
            break
        a = AnalyzeFrequency(path)
        a.analyze()
        print("Analyzed file in %.4f seconds" % a._time)
        add_to_append_queue(a.get_results())

    #append_queue.join()
    #append_queue_process.join()
    print str(append_queue.qsize())
    database.save_db()
    print("Database saved in %.4f seconds" % database.save_time)
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

**UPDATE 2**

This is the database code:

```
class FrequencyStore:

    def __init__(self):
        self.sorter = Sorter()
        self.db = {}
        self.load_time = -1
        self.save_time = -1
        self.append_time = -1
        self.sort_time = -1

    def load_db(self):
        start_time = time.time()

        try:
            file = open("results.txt", 'r')
        except:
            raise IOError

        self.db = {}
        for line in file:
            word, count = line.strip("\n").split("=")
            self.db[word] = int(count)
        file.close()

        self.load_time = time.time() - start_time

    def save_db(self):
        start_time = time.time()

        _db = []
        for key in self.db:
            _db.append([key, self.db[key]])
        _db = self.sort(_db)

        try:
            file = open("results.txt", 'w')
        except:
            raise IOError

        file.truncate(0)
        for x in _db:
            file.write(x[0] + "=" + str(x[1]) + "\n")
        file.close()

        self.save_time = time.time() - start_time

    def create_sorted_db(self):
        _temp_db = []
        for key in self.db:
            _temp_db.append([key, self.db[key]])
        _temp_db = self.sort(_temp_db)
        _temp_db.reverse()
        return _temp_db

    def get_db(self):
        return self.db

    def sort(self, _list):
        start_time = time.time()

        _list = self.sorter.mergesort(_list)
        _list.reverse()

        self.sort_time = time.time() - start_time
        return _list

    def append(self, _list):
        start_time = time.time()

        for x in _list:
            if x[0] not in self.db:
                self.db[x[0]] = x[1]
            else:
                self.db[x[0]] += x[1]

        self.append_time = time.time() - start_time
```

Comment: A `Queue.Queue` does not work across processes.  So first change is to use a `multiprocessing.Queue` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comments suggest you're trying to run this on Windows.  As I said in a comment,

> If you're running this on Windows, it can't work - Windows doesn't
>   have `fork()`, so each process gets its own Queue and they have nothing
>   to do with each other. The entire module is imported "from scratch" by
>   each process on Windows. You'll need to create the Queue in `main()`,
>   and pass it as an argument to the worker function.

Here's fleshing out what you need to do to make it portable, although I removed all the database stuff because it's irrelevant to the problems you've described so far.  I also removed the `daemon` fiddling, because that's *usually* just a lazy way to avoid shutting down things cleanly, and often as not will come back to bite you later:

```
def process_append_queue(append_queue):
    while True:
        x = append_queue.get()
        if x is None:
            break
        print("processed %d" % x)
    print("worker done")

def main():
    import multiprocessing as mp

    append_queue = mp.Queue(10)
    append_queue_process = mp.Process(target=process_append_queue, args=(append_queue,))
    append_queue_process.start()
    for i in range(100):
        append_queue.put(i)
    append_queue.put(None)  # tell worker we're done
    append_queue_process.join()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

The output is the "obvious" stuff:

```
processed 0
processed 1
processed 2
processed 3
processed 4
...
processed 96
processed 97
processed 98
processed 99
worker done
```

Note:  because Windows doesn't (can't) `fork()`, it's impossible for worker processes to *inherit* any Python object on Windows.  Each process runs the entire program from its start.  That's why your original program couldn't work:  each process created its own `Queue`, wholly unrelated to the `Queue` in the other process.  In the approach shown above, only the main process creates a `Queue`, and the main process passes it (as an argument) to the worker process.

Comment: The code works! One more thing, If you take a look at my FrequencyAnalysis.py you will see the FrequencyStorage class. If I call the append method from another process, will it not update the instance variable in that class. I am passing the object as a parameter like you did with queue.

Comment: That would be a different question entirely, so make the test case as small as possible and post a different question.  In general, you shouldn't expect any mutation of any object to be visible across processes.  The memory is not shared.  A `multiprocessing.Queue` works because it's implemented from the ground up to _make_ mutations visible across processes - and that doesn't happen by magic (it happens by under-the-covers interprocess pipes communicating info about mutations among processes, guarded by interprocess semaphores protecting against simultaneous mutations).

Answer (score 4):

`queue.Queue` is thread-safe, but doesn't work across processes.  This is quite easy to fix, though.  Instead of:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from Queue import Queue
```

You want:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
```

Comment: I'm a blind screen reader user and can't read a traceback in an image, sorry.  It also doesn't help people who Google for the text in your traceback at a later date.  Preferably, update the question, post the traceback in a comment, or create a new one.

Comment: Your database isn't process-safe.  You're creating the database instance in the main Python process, then telling Python to do something with it in a completely different one.  So the call to `database.append` is hanging, not the call to `Queue.get`.  The whole point of using a queue is to avoid this exact problem.

Comment: I just tested the Queue.get and the database.append methods with a print statement after each. The Queue.get statement never proceeds, it just blocks. I also updated the original question with the code from the database.

Comment: Just as I suspected. When I run this on linux, it works with no problems whatsoever. Maybe it is due to something in windows?

Comment: Impossible to say without a runnable sample.

Comment: If you're running this on Windows, it can't work - Windows doesn't have `fork()`, so each process gets its own `Queue` and they have nothing to do with each other.  The entire module is imported "from scratch" by each process on Windows.  You'll need to create the `Queue` _in_ `main()`, and pass it as an argument to the worker function.

Comment: Thanks for that info, it is very helpful!