# Requests and multiprocessing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, queue, multiprocessing

So i'm trying to use `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` on several websites in the same time and for some reason i can't make it work.
Here is a full example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import randint

# Define an output queue


class Spider(object):
    """docstring for Spider"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(Spider, self).__init__()

    # define a example function
    def rand_string(length, output):
        random_post=randint(1000000,9999999)
        response=requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/'+str(random_post))
        soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
        try:
            title=soup.find('a',{'class':'question-hyperlink'}).string
        except:
            title="not found"

        output.put(title)

    # Setup a list of processes that we want to run
    def run(self):

        output = mp.Queue()
        processes = [mp.Process(target=Spider.rand_string, args=(x, output)) for x in range(10)]

        for p in processes:
            p.start()

        # Exit the completed processes

        for p in processes:
            p.join()

        # Get process results from the output queue

        results = [output.get() for p in processes]
        print(results)

# Run processes

if __name__ == '__main__':

    spider=Spider()
    spider.run()
```

Comment: have you tried making sure everything runs smoothly when single threaded? multiprocessing can make it hard to debug the child processes

Comment: There's otherwise nothing glaring in the code you've posted, so your problem is elsewhere..

Comment: @Aaron, single threaded works very well but i'm not happy with the execution time. None of the functions use same resources/files

Comment: well, atm I don't see anything wrong in the code you've posted. are all the functions similar enough you could condense into one function and provide say another argument (website to search)? If so, I'd personally try to do that and use the already built `multiprocessing.pool`

Comment: @Aaron I think it has to do with the fact that i'm running from a Windows machine, but i didn't figure out how to change the code yet... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37244168/multiprocessing-queue-get-hangs

Comment: could you possibly write a test case example of f1 - f4 (basically include a minimally working version of your class that display similar behavior) so I can have a complete example to run and test?

Comment: @Aaron each of the functions takes the word, makes some subsequent post requests on a site and gets some text, there's nothing complicated about them, but you're right, i just took this [link](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_multiprocessing.html) and it worked, i'll try to figure it out...must be something of the functions...

Comment: @Aaron i built it, i'll edit the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a bunch of debug print statements to follow your flow and came to a few conclusions...

1. you may sometimes run into recursion depth limits with bs4...
2. the previous answer you linked (in comments) is indeed relevant to your problem.
3. windows not having `fork()` is a huge pain.

Your primary error was in `rand_string()` with the line:

```
title=soup.find('a',{'class':'question-hyperlink'}).string
```

This was returning a `<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>` rather than a `<class str>`. When this was passed to `mp.Queue.put()` the attempt to pickle it so it could be sent through the internal pipe failed with a recursion error, thereby stalling queue. I'm not sure if it's actually possible to send bs4 elements through a pickled pipe, (perhaps if you convert reference loops to weakrefs?) but it's much easier to just always send simple python objects. I also moved the creation of the queue to the main context (outside `spider.run()`) though that's not specifically necessary as long as it's only executed by the main thread. Here's my debugging code in it's final iteration so you can follow my testing methodology:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, current_process
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import randint
import sys
#sys.setrecursionlimit(1000)

class Spider(object):
    """docstring for Spider"""

    # define a example function
    @staticmethod
    def rand_string(length, output):

        print("{} entry point".format(current_process().name))
        random_post=randint(1000000,9999999)
        response=requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/'+str(random_post))
        print("{} got request response".format(current_process().name))
        soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
        try:
            title = soup.find('a',{'class':'question-hyperlink'}).string
        except:
            title = "not found"

        print("{} got title: '{}' of type: {}".format(current_process().name, title, type(title)))

        ###### This did it ######
        title = str(title) #fix or fake news?

        output.put([title,current_process().name])
        output.close()
        print("{} exit point".format(current_process().name))


    # Setup a list of processes that we want to run
#    @staticmethod
    def run(self, outq):
        processes = []
        for x in range(5):
                processes.append(Process(target=self.rand_string, name="process_{}".format(x), args=(x, outq,),) )
                print("creating process_{}".format(x))

        for p in processes:
            p.start()
            print("{} started".format(p.name))

        # Exit the completed processes
        for p in processes:
            p.join()
            print("successuflly joined {}".format(p.name))

        # Get process results from the output queue
        print("joined all workers")
#        return None
        out = []
        while not outq.empty():
            result = outq.get()
            print("got {}".format(result))
            out.append(result)
        return out

# Run processes
if __name__ == '__main__':
    outq = Queue()
    spider=Spider()
    out = spider.run(outq)
    print("done")
```

and the output of running said code:

```
creating process_0
creating process_1
creating process_2
creating process_3
creating process_4
process_0 started
process_1 started
process_2 started
process_3 started
process_4 started
process_2 entry point
process_2 got request response
process_2 got title: 'not found' of type: <class 'str'>
process_2 exit point
process_0 entry point
process_0 got request response
process_0 got title: 'Starting Activity when video is finished playing' of type: <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
process_0 exit point
successuflly joined process_0
process_3 entry point
process_3 got request response
process_3 got title: 'Just don't understand the point of these typedefs' of type: <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
process_3 exit point
process_1 entry point
process_1 got request response
process_1 got title: 'Import button + File browse field in admin product grid in magento' of type: <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
process_1 exit point
process_4 entry point
process_4 got request response
process_4 got title: 'How can I do a query with subselect' of type: <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
process_4 exit point
successuflly joined process_1
successuflly joined process_2
successuflly joined process_3
successuflly joined process_4
joined all workers
got ['not found', 'process_2']
got ['Starting Activity when video is finished playing', 'process_0']
got ["Just don't understand the point of these typedefs", 'process_3']
got ['Import button + File browse field in admin product grid in magento', 'process_1']
got ['How can I do a query with subselect', 'process_4']
done
```

Comment: And they say heroes don't exist!! Thx alot, i tried 1231441 things, i even remember now reading about pickling the queue objects but i didn't figure that the bs4.tag was the problem. Also, thank you for rewriting the thing, it helps me learn how to write more readable code. Big up for you, thx!

Comment: You're welcome @Mike. I'm probably gonna burst your bubble now though by mentioning that for this application, Threads would have been much better. your particular application was i/o bound with the http requests, so the added overhead of processes vs threads probably wasn't worth the extra processing power. Additionally you could have entirely avoided the queue issue as threads share memory and you can simply write to shared resources with a few locks [(mutex)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) to prevent accidental overwrites..

Comment: also keep in mind that print statements from child processes or threads might get buffered and actually written later.. if you want things to print (somewhat) immediately, you have to call `sys.stdout.write("stuff")` followed by `sys.stdout.flush()` It would seem in my example, each process never flushed it's output to stdout until it terminated, which is why each set of 4 print statements were grouped together.

Comment: I did manage to use threads but it didn't improve my run time at all. I was aiming to have 4 processes which are further split into multiple threads. Your solution worked but on my real script i'm still having a hard time queuing a list of dictionaries through that queue.queue. Great help and Thx for the print suggestion!