# Implementing "competing" processes in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to implement a function that takes 2 functions as arguments, runs both, returns the value of the function that returns first and kills the slower function before it finishes its execution. 
My problem is that when I try to empty the Queue object I use to collect the return values, I get stuck.
Is there a more 'correct' way to handle this scenario or even an existing module? If not, can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?
Here is my code (the implementation of the above function is 'run_both()'):

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from time import sleep


Q = mp.Queue()

def dump_queue(queue):
    result = []
    for i in iter(queue.get, 'STOP'):
        result.append(i)
    return result

def rabbit(x):
    sleep(10)
    Q.put(x)

def turtle(x):
    sleep(30)
    Q.put(x)

def run_both(a,b):
    a.start()
    b.start()
    while a.is_alive() and b.is_alive():
            sleep(1)
    if a.is_alive():
            a.terminate()
    else:
            b.terminate()
    a.join()
    b.join()
    return dump_queue(Q)


p1 = mp.Process(target=rabbit, args=(1,))
p1 = mp.Process(target=turtle, args=(2,))
run_both(p1, p2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to call 2 or more functions with `multiprocessing` and return the fastest result.  There are a few important things to note however.

1. Running `multiprocessing` code in IDLE sometimes causes problems. This example works, but I did run into that issue trying to solve this.
2. Multiprocessing code should start from inside a `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause, or else it will be run again if the main module is re-imported by another process. read the multiprocessing doc page for more info.
3. The result queue is passed directly to each process that uses it. When you use the queue by referencing a global name in the module, the code fails on windows because a new instance of the queue is used by each process. Read more here [Multiprocessing Queue.get() hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37244168/multiprocessing-queue-get-hangs)

I have also added a bit of a feature here to know which process' result was actually used.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import random

def task(value):
    # our dummy task is to sleep for a random amount of time and
    # return the given arg value
    time.sleep(random.random())
    return value

def process(q, idx, fn, args):
    # simply call function fn with args, and push its result in the queue with its index
    q.put([fn(*args), idx])

def fastest(calls):
    queue = mp.Queue()
    # we must pass the queue directly to each process that may use it
    # or else on Windows, each process will have its own copy of the queue
    # making it useless

    procs = []
    # create a 'mp.Process' that calls our 'process' for each call and start it
    for idx, call in enumerate(calls):
        fn = call[0]
        args = call[1:]
        p = mp.Process(target=process, args=(queue, idx, fn, args))
        procs.append(p)
        p.start()
    # wait for the queue to have something
    result, idx = queue.get()
    for proc in procs: # kill all processes that may still be running
        proc.terminate()
        # proc may be using queue, so queue may be corrupted.
        # https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=queue#multiprocessing.Process.terminate
        # we no longer need queue though so this is fine
    return result, idx

if __name__ == '__main__':

    from datetime import datetime

    start = datetime.now()
    print(start)
    # to be compatible with 'fastest', each call is a list with the first
    # element being callable, followed by args to be passed
    calls = [
        [task, 1],
        [task, 'hello'],
        [task, [1,2,3]]
        ]
    val, idx = fastest(calls)
    end = datetime.now()
    print(end)
    print('elapsed time:', end-start)
    print('returned value:', val)
    print('from call at index', idx)
```

Example output:

```
2019-12-21 04:01:09.525575
2019-12-21 04:01:10.171891
elapsed time: 0:00:00.646316
returned value: hello
from call at index 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the typo on the penultimate line which should read:

```
p2 = mp.Process(target=turtle, args=(2,))       # not p1
```

the simplest change you can make to get the program to work is to add:

```
Q.put('STOP')
```

to the end of `turtle()` and `rabbit()`.

---

You also don't really need to keep looping watching if the processes are alive, by definition if you just read the message queue and receive `STOP`, one of them has finished, so you could replace `run_both()` with:

```
def run_both(a,b):
    a.start()
    b.start()
    result =  dump_queue(Q)
    a.terminate()
    b.terminate()
    return result
```

---

You may also need to think about what happens if both processes put some messages in the queue at much the same time. They could get mixed up. Maybe consider using 2 queues, or joining all the results up into a single message rather than appending multiple values together from `queue.get()`